# netstandard2.0: аналог для Path.RelativePath не работает

Tags: c#, файловая-система, .net-standard

воспользовался [вот этой реализацией для Path.RelativePath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/340454/11621099) (в netstandard2.0 ее нет, нужен обходной путь)
тестирую, она очень неправильно работает.
сравниваю два пути:

> D:\sn\pn\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\root\testfolder
> D:\sn\pn\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\root

сравнивал в обоих направлениях (вдруг перепутал) - оба неправильные:

> root\testfolder
> ..\root

не понимаю, в каком месте эти варианты могут оказаться правильными!?
ожидал я что-то вроде этого:

> .\testfolder
> testfolder
> ..\

Comment: Попробуйтре прибавить в конце каталога ``\``. Там это обсуждается в комментариях.

Comment: точно! думал, что в таком залайканом ответе ошибок нет - не смотрел коменты

Comment: только позже понял, что оно не может отличить папку от файла когда это просто строка